# How to convert string into int in csv file?

Tags: command-line, scripts

I have a `fb.csv` file like below;

```
"Source","Destination","Time"  
"192.168.137.174","157.240.10.18","12:26:25.782658000"
"10.0.138.163","157.240.10.18","12:26:25.782766000"
"157.240.10.13","192.168.137.174","12:26:36.488264000"
"157.240.10.13","10.0.138.163","12:26:36.488178000"
"157.240.10.23","192.168.137.174","12:26:41.808511000"
"157.240.10.23","10.0.138.163","12:26:41.808440000"
"10.0.138.163","157.240.10.18","12:26:52.275093000"
"192.168.137.174","157.240.10.18","12:26:52.275025000"
```

The time (in column 3) is a string and I would like to convert it to an integer as I would like to proceed with an operation to find duration. And also I want to delete all numbers after "." in the time column.

Desired output:

```
"Source","Destination","Time"  
"192.168.137.174","157.240.10.18","12:26:25"
"10.0.138.163","157.240.10.18","12:26:25"
"157.240.10.13","192.168.137.174","12:26:36"
"157.240.10.13","10.0.138.163","12:26:36"
"157.240.10.23","192.168.137.174","12:26:41"
"157.240.10.23","10.0.138.163","12:26:41"
"10.0.138.163","157.240.10.18","12:26:52"
"192.168.137.174","157.240.10.18","12:26:52"
```

Is there any method or function I could use to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sed` in this way:

```
sed -E 's/\:([0-9])([0-9])\..*"/\:\1\2"/g' fb.csv
```

Better regular expression was provided by @GlennJackman:

> A colon is not special and does not need to be escaped. You don't need
>   to capture each digit separately. It does not need to be a global
>   replacement because the first one will erase the rest of the line:
>   `s/(:[0-9][0-9])\.[0-9]+/\1/`:

```
sed -E 's/(:[0-9][0-9])\.[0-9]+/\1/' fb.csv
```

The most lightweights solution without extended regex was provided by @Dessert:

```
sed 's/\.[0-9]*"$/"/' fb.csv
```

---

To convert the third column into [integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer), If I understand correctly, we should add second expression:

```
sed -e 's/\.[0-9]*"$/"/' -e 's/\://g' fb.csv
```

---

If the output looks adequately we can add the option `-i.bak` to replace the values in their places and create a backup file simultaneously:

```
sed -e 's/\.[0-9]*"$/"/' -e 's/\://g' fb.csv -i.bak
```

---

References:

- [Sed, a stream editor - gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)
- [FreeBSD Man Pages: Sed](http://www.ipnom.com/FreeBSD-Man-Pages/sed.1.html) | [Ubuntu Man Pages: Sed](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/sed.1.html)
- [GNU OS: Overview of Regular Expression Syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html)
- [RexExr - an online tool to learn, build, & test Regular Expressions](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: pa4080 thanks. Is the string type in Time column converted to int after the command?

Comment: @Ayu I could not understood this part of the question. An *integer* is a *variable* that specifically holds a numerical value. If we remove the character `:` from the sting `12:26:52` it should look as integer - `122652`. I will update the answer.

Comment: A colon is not special and does not need to be escaped. You don't need to capture each digit separately. It does not need to be a global replacement because the first one will erase the rest of the line: `s/(:[0-9][0-9])\.[0-9]+/\1/`

Comment: Thanks, @glennjackman, I will add this comment into the answer. I'm still learning :)

Comment: Looks like you're on a good path. Keep it up

Comment: Why not just `sed 's/\.[0-9]*"$/"/' fb.csv`?

Comment: Hi, @dessert, because I couldn't realise how to use `$` in this case. Thanks for the example!

Comment: @Ayu, if you wish complete `awk` solution: `awk -F\" '{gsub(/\..*$/, "", $(NF-1) )}{gsub(/\:/, "")}1' OFS=\" fb.csv`

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk` to remove anything after a dot in last field.

```
awk -F\" '{gsub(/\..*$/, "", $(NF-1) )}1' OFS=\" infile
```

and use as following if you need to do calculating difference between two times in consecutive lines in seconds.

```
awk -F\" 'function abs(x) {return x<0 ? -x : x} 
    { gsub(/\..*$/, "", $(NF-1) ) }
    NR>1{ split( $(NF-1), ary, /:/); t_sec= 3600*ary[1] + 60*ary[2] + ary[3];
          getline; N=$(NF-1); split( $N, ary, /:/); t_sec_N= 3600*ary[1] + 60*ary[2] + ary[3];
          print abs(t_sec - t_sec_N);
}' OFS=\" infile
```

function borrowed from [@glenn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8172014/4023950)

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed -E 's/(.*)"([0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*)\.[0-9]*"/\1\2/' fb.csv
```

Getting rid of the `:` so that last column can be operated on:

```
sed -Ee 's/(.*)"([0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*)\.[0-9]*"/\1\2/' -e 's/\://g' fb.csv
```